# How to create a relative symbolic link to a non-existing file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
ln -s foo /some/path/to/bar
```

doesn't ask whether foo exists and just creates a relative symbolic link "bar" that points to a nonexistent foo.

What is the python equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import os

os.symlink("foo", "/some/path/to/bar")
```

Because the first argument is not an absolute path, this will create a link `/some/path/to/bar` pointing to the (possibly nonexistent) `/some/path/to/foo`.